# Fix progress bar bug, when 0% it moves out the progress bar

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a bug when i have 0% or more up to 6% it looks bugged and starts going out the bar how do i fix this?

when it's 0% it creates white space outside the progress bar when in reality it should just dissapear and slowly progress as the number increases. But that is not the case here i have tried fixing the width when the number is 0 but that didn't work

```
if (completionPercentage === 0) {
      progressWidth = 0; // Set progressWidth to 0 if completion is 0
    } else {
      progressWidth = Math.max(progressWidth, borderRadius * 2); // Ensure progressWidth is at least borderRadius * 2
      progressWidth = Math.min(progressWidth, barWidth - borderRadius * 2); // Ensure progressWidth doesn't exceed available width
    }
```

This is the code below:

```
const {
    createCanvas
} = require('canvas');

module.exports = {
    name: 'api/progressbar',
    run: async (req, res) => {
        const {
            name,
            completed,
            total
        } = req.query;

        if (!name || !completed || !total) return res.status(400).send('Missing one or more required parameters');

        const task = {
            name,
            completed,
            total
        };

        // Calculate the completion percentage
        const completionPercentage = Math.round((task.completed / task.total) * 100);

        // Create a new canvas and context
        const canvas = createCanvas(400, 100);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, canvas.height);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, '#2a2e35');
        //gradient.addColorStop(1, '#FFF');
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Draw the gray background of the progress bar
        const barWidth = canvas.width - 100;
        const barHeight = 30;
        const barX = (canvas.width - barWidth) / 2;
        const barY = (canvas.height - barHeight) / 2;
        const borderRadius = barHeight / 2; // Adjust the radius for the roundness

        ctx.fillStyle = '#484b4e';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(barX + borderRadius, barY);
        ctx.lineTo(barX + barWidth - borderRadius, barY);
        ctx.arcTo(barX + barWidth, barY, barX + barWidth, barY + borderRadius, borderRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(barX + barWidth, barY + barHeight - borderRadius);
        ctx.arcTo(barX + barWidth, barY + barHeight, barX + barWidth - borderRadius, barY + barHeight, borderRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(barX + borderRadius, barY + barHeight);
        ctx.arcTo(barX, barY + barHeight, barX, barY + barHeight - borderRadius, borderRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(barX, barY + borderRadius);
        ctx.arcTo(barX, barY, barX + borderRadius, barY, borderRadius);
        ctx.fill();

        // Draw the white progress bar on top of the gray background
        let progressWidth = (task.completed / task.total) * barWidth;

        ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(barX + borderRadius, barY);
        ctx.lineTo(barX + progressWidth - borderRadius, barY);
        ctx.arcTo(barX + progressWidth, barY, barX + progressWidth, barY + borderRadius, borderRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(barX + progressWidth, barY + barHeight - borderRadius);
        ctx.arcTo(barX + progressWidth, barY + barHeight, barX + progressWidth - borderRadius, barY + barHeight, borderRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(barX + borderRadius, barY + barHeight);
        ctx.arcTo(barX, barY + barHeight, barX, barY + barHeight - borderRadius, borderRadius);
        ctx.lineTo(barX, barY + borderRadius);
        ctx.arcTo(barX, barY, barX + borderRadius, barY, borderRadius);
        ctx.fill();

        // Draw the completion percentage text
        ctx.font = 'bold 28px Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(`${completionPercentage}%`, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 + 10);

        // Draw the task name text
        ctx.font = 'bold 23px Arial';
        ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
        ctx.textAlign = 'center';
        ctx.fillText(task.name, canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - 30);

        // Convert the canvas to a PNG buffer and send it as the response
        const buffer = canvas.toBuffer('image/png');
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
            'Content-Length': buffer.length
        });
        res.end(buffer);
    }
};
```

Comment: How do you do the run code button?

Comment: [Use this button in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX4Eo.png)